# Use of underline and siunitx in a table

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have a table of numbers that are aligned using the 'S' format of siunitx (so they are aligned by the decimal point). I need to mark the statistically significant numbers somehow, and using bold font or asterisks to mark these don't make them stand out very well. I am not allowed to use colour in the table, so I was thinking of trying underlining. However, if I use `\underline{}`, the underlined numbers are no longer aligned by the decimal point and are left aligned instead.

Is there any way I can underline items whilst keeping them aligned by the decimal point?

Here is a basic version of the code for the table I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx,booktabs,threeparttable,multirow,array,graphicx}
\robustify\bfseries
\robustify\tnote

\begin{document}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math,table-align-text-post=false}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Insert caption here}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \begin{tabular}{SS}
        \toprule
        {Column 1} & {Column 2}\\
        \midrule
        7.1 & 4.2\\
        \underline{8.7} & 6.5\\
        9.3 & \underline{1.0}\\
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Not sure how to post an image of what the output looks like.

I did have a search online for anyone asking a similar question, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine with the command `\uline` from the `ulem` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx,booktabs,threeparttable,multirow,array,graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\robustify\bfseries
\robustify\uline
\robustify\tnote


\begin{document}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math,table-align-text-post=false}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Insert caption here}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \begin{tabular}{SS}
        \toprule
        {Column 1} & {Column 2}\\
        \midrule
        7.1 & 4.2\\
        \uline{8.7} & 6.5\\
        9.3 & \uline{1.0}\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that you have to load `ulem` with the option `normalem` if you don't want the command `\emph` to behave as `\uline` and you also have to `\robustify` the `\uline` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did try the `\uline` thing with `ulem`, but I hadn't done the `\robustify` bit. I will try that now to see if it works.

Comment: Added the package and did `\robustify\uline` and it all works perfectly! So frustrating when you miss little things like that, so very grateful for this website!!

Comment: I now have another problem related to this. In the `\sisetup`, I have added `table-format=2.1` to reduce the space each number was taking up. When I do this, the underline values don't align with the non-underlined ones. Is there any way I can fix this without removing the `table-format`?

Comment: @emmalgale Please ask a follow-up question for this.

Comment: Ok, I will do :)

Comment: @karlkoeller please try some number which is not 1.1. For me, the `\uline` approach does not work then. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi It works fine for me with every number I tried. Can you give some more info?

Comment: @karlkoeller Just do `\uline{8.77} & 6.5\\ ` and the decimal alignment (which, I guess, is what was wanted by the `S`-column) vanishes.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I don't see the point. Use `S[table-format = 1.2]` as a column specifier. Nothing to do with `\uline`.

Comment: @karlkoeller If you set `\uline{9.3}` then as well, it will get distorted again. If you leave `SS` and don't use `\uline` at all, the decimal point alignment works even without `table-format=1.2` or alike. That is why I think your solution is having some mistake. The follow up of the OP goes in similar direction, of course.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi You're right. I don't have a workaround, I'm sorry.

Comment: Me neither. Well. I just wanted to be sure, it is not just on my system. Thanks for your time. If someone stumbles on this discussion. Here is some work to do: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161032