# Problem with uline and table-format in siunitx table

Tags: tables, siunitx

I asked a previous question about underlining data in a table when using the siunitx `S` column definition (see [Use of underline and siunitx in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159623/use-of-underline-and-siunitx-in-a-table/159634?noredirect=1#comment368050_159634)). The advice given was perfect until I added `\sisetup{table-format=2.1}` to reduce the amount of space being used up the numbers. I have managed to get my table spaced out perfectly now, so I don't really want to remove the `\sisetup`, but this line means that any underlined values in the table are now not aligned by decimal point.

Is there any way to combine underlining with this `\sisetup`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx,booktabs,threeparttable,multirow,array,graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\robustify\bfseries
\robustify\uline
\sisetup{detect-weight        = true,
         detect-inline-weight = math,
         tight-spacing        = true,
         table-format         = 2.1,
         }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Insert caption here}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \begin{tabular}{SS}
        \toprule
            {Column 1} & {Column 2}\\
        \midrule
            7.1 & 4.2\\
            \uline{8.7} & 6.5\\
            9.3 & \uline{1.0}\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to work with `dcolumn` if that helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258799

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I'm afraid this is really not going to work with `siunitx`: you can't apply underlining in a way that's compatible with boxing up material.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here, I just get clever with an `\llap`, which I incorporate into `Uline`.  Not sure if it will handle all cases, but I am willing to adapt further as needed.  This first version is simplest, but can get confused if the table data does not conform to the `table-format`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx,booktabs,threeparttable,multirow,array,graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\robustify\bfseries
\robustify\uline
\sisetup{detect-weight        = true,
         detect-inline-weight = math,
         tight-spacing        = true,
         table-format         = 2.1,
         }
\def\Uline#1{#1\llap{\uline{\phantom{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Insert caption here}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \begin{tabular}{SS}
        \toprule
            {Column 1} & {Column 2}\\
        \midrule
            7.1 & 4.2\\
            \Uline{8.7} & 6.5\\
            9.3 & \Uline{11.0}\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This alternate version is more robust, if the data entries do not conform to the `table-format`.  However, the definition of `\Decimal` must be set in accord with `table-format`.  Here are some corresponding values:

`table-format = 2.0  ---> \def\Decimal{}`

`table-format = 2.1  ---> \def\Decimal{.0}`

`table-format = 2.2  ---> \def\Decimal{.00}`

EDITED to handle case of `\Uline{11.}`, which auto-adds a zero following the decimal point.  RE-EDITED to place cursor at end of data entry, so that, for example, `\Uline{11.2}345` behaves as expected, with the `11.2` underlined and the `345` not so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx,booktabs,threeparttable,multirow,array,graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\robustify\bfseries
\robustify\uline
\sisetup{detect-weight        = true,
         detect-inline-weight = math,
         tight-spacing        = true,
         table-format         = 2.2,
         }
\def\Decimal{.00}% This structure should corresponds to the ".2" of "table-format"
\def\Uline#1{\Ulinehelp#1 }
\def\Ulinehelp#1.#2 {%
  #1.#2\setbox0=\hbox{#1\Decimal}\hspace{-\wd0}{\if\relax#2\relax%
    \uline{\phantom{#1.0}}\else\uline{\phantom{#1.#2}}\fi}%
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Insert caption here}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \begin{tabular}{SS}
        \toprule
            {Column 1} & {Column 2}\\
        \midrule
            \Uline{7.10} & \Uline{544.2123}\\
            \Uline{8.777} & 6.5\\
            9.3 & \Uline{11.}\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great :) I haven't got time to see if it works in my table at the moment, but I will mark it as correct anyway!