# How to make a table with multiple subheading columns spanning the entire table width?

Tags: tables, tabularx, nicematrix

I tried using multiple tabularx environments inside a table environment, but this leads to issues with the entire text being aligned towards the left and not matching with the column headings, which in this example below are `V1, V2, V3`:

I'm getting the error for the following code (I tried removing \hline but that doesn't help):

```
Misplaced \noalign.: You have used a \hline command in the wrong place, probably outside a table. If the \hline command is written inside a table, try including \\ before it.
```

```
\begin{table}[]

    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{SSSS} \hline
        {$ $} & {$metric$} & {$metric$} & {$metric$} \\ \hline
        \textbf{class 1}  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{HEADING}
        \midrule
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0  &  0\\ 
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0   & 0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0   & 0  &  0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0 &  0 \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0  &  0\\ 
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0   & 0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0   & 0  &  0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0 &  0 \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{HEADING}
        \midrule
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0  &  0 \\ 
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0   & 0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0   & 0  &  0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0 &  0 \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0  &  0\\ 
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0   & 0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0   & 0  &  0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0 &  0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}


    \caption{caption here}
    \label{table:results}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: if you are getting errors with your tex code someone will help, but you need to show the code, add a small complete document that shows the problem. tabularx X columns are p columns so you can center text with `\centering\arraybackslash`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, I've added the tex code and error I'm getting.

Comment: we can not run your fragment as it is incomplete, but in your title you mention tabularx but the code fragment uses` tabular*` but a `tabular*` will not expand unless you use `\extracolsep`  . The error you show is unrelated and simply that you have forgotten the `\\ ` after `\textbf{HEADING}`

Comment: Please see my answer with a comment on the problem of underline.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you intended something like this (note you are not using `tabularx` at all.  Personally I would use a normal `tabular` here: stretching the columns to full with just makes the table harder to read, but this shows it full width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}% don't use an empty argument []

    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lSSS@{}} \\\toprule
% don't use math mode to get italics!!!!
%        {$ $} & {$metric$} & {$metric$} & {$metric$} \\ \hline
    & {\textit{metric}}&{\textit{metric}}&{\textit{metric}}\\\midrule
        \textbf{class 1}  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \midrule
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{HEADING}}\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0  &  0\\ 
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0   & 0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0   & 0  &  0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0 &  0 \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0  &  0\\ 
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0   & 0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0   & 0  &  0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0 &  0 \\
        \midrule
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{HEADING}}\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0  &  0 \\ 
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0   & 0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0   & 0  &  0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0 &  0 \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0  &  0\\ 
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0   & 0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0   & 0  &  0  \\
        \textbf{model (1)}  & 0  &  0 &  0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}


    \caption{caption here}
    \label{table:results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If instead you use

```
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{lSSS} \\\toprule
```

Then it looks like

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I just have a quick follow up, when I underline things it shifts the element underlined, how do i prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

This alternative uses the package `nicematrix`. I followed the general design of the drawing with a vertical line.

Vertical lines are generally discouraged in technical publications, but of course they are useful in many situations. Some packages have difficulty joining vertical and horizontal lines (see the second figure). This is not the case with `nicematrix`.

I added a new  column type to allow the expanding of the last 3 columns, as a percentage of the text width.

Finally, several elements were underlined without noticeable consequences. Note also the correct centering of "*metric*".

**NOTE**  To underline under S columns use  `\uline` from the `ulem` package.
(loaded as `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159634/161015

[image: A]

Problems when joining lines

[image: x]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}} % size of the column as a percent of textwidth    
    
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit = 5pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 5pt} %expand the cells vertically and horizontally  
    
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{>\bfseries{c} | P{0.2} P{0.2}  P{0.2}}  % first column in bf
              & \textit{metric}&\textit{metric}&\textit{\underline{metric}}\\
    \midrule
    \textbf{class 1}  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \midrule
              &\Block{1-3}{\textbf{\underline{HEADING}}}\\
    \midrule
    model (1) & 0  & 0  &  0 \\ 
    \underline{model (1)} & 0  &  0   & 0  \\
    model (1) & 0  & 0  &  0 \\
    model (1) & 0  & 0  &  0 \\
    \midrule
    model (1) & 0  & 0  & 0  \\ 
    model (1) & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
    model (1) & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
    model (1) & \underline{0}  &  0 &  0 \\
    \midrule
              &\Block{1-3}{\textbf{HEADING}}\\
    \midrule
    model (1) & 0  & 0  &  0  \\ 
    model (1) & 0  & 0  &  0  \\
    model (1) & 0  & 0  &  0  \\
    model (1) & 0  & 0  &  0  \\
    \midrule
    model (1) & 0  & 0  & 0  \\ 
    model (1) & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
    model (1) & 0  &  \underline{0}  &  0  \\
    model (1) & 0  & 0  &  0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}

    \caption{caption here}
    \label{table:results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```